# How to link a web page to another web page using which has accordion page using events and jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, accordion

I have a index page where I want to link to a case studies pages (html) which has an accordion jquery menu nav bar driven by event triggers.

How do I link these from the index page so that when a user clicks on it will take you to the case studies page opening the relevant page in the accordion jquery section.

I have tried using this code, on the index page but this does not work.

a href="church-clock-case-studies.html" onClick="$('#test3Handle0').click()">Lyndon Hall

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass an argument to the target page. The easiest way to do so would be using the hash, i.e. make your href point to `church-clock-case-studies.html#yourpage`.

In church-clock-case-studies.html you'll then use `location.hash` to set the default page of the accordion. For instructions on how to set the default accordion page, have a look at the [jQuery UI Accordion help](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active).

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure I understand you, I ma afraid I am not very technical. I dont want to link to the default page of the accordion but for each link in the index page to link to each of the appropriate pages in the accordion page. So when click on link it opens the appropriate accordion page. I hope I have made my self clear.

Comment: So accordion and links are on the same page? In this case use `$('#yourAccordion').accordion('activate', INDEX);` on your links' onclick handlers and replace INDEX with the index of the accordion page you want to show.

Comment: No on the home page (index) we have for example : Link1 to accordion section1 - accordion resides on case study html page. Link2 is also on index page to accordion section2 - accordion resides on case study html page. etc. What I want is when a user clicks on link 3 on the home page it will take you to the case study page opening section3 of the accordion showing the relevant ifon.

Answer (score 1):

As ThiefMaster already said, you need to pass the name of the active section you want in your accordion somehow. The easiest way to do it, as ThiefMaster also suggested, would be using a hash, as in "#argumentToBePassed" which should work in your case.

Basically you need an accordion which can identify an active state based on input provided; in this case the input is provided through the URL hash.

For a detailed walkthrough of this method (and more), you might want to check out http://www.michaeljacobdavis.com/tutorials/statesavingaccordion.html which I found very helpful.

You need to do this:

1. Assuming you are using the accordion widget in JQuery UI, set the "navigation" parameter to "true" in your call to accordion() like so; `$("#yourAccordion").accordion({navigation:true});//while initializing accordion`

   or

   `$("#yourAccordion").accordion("option", "navigation" ,true);//set it later in the script`
2. Say, you want link3 on homepage to open #section3 in your accordion, mark up the section3 "container element" on the target page(church-clock-case-studies.html) with id="section3". Also, point your header link in your accordion to "#section3".
3. Make your link3 on homepage point to church-clock-case-studies.html#section3 .

That should do it for you. Although, I have tested it in a different scenario where I need to preserve the state of currently open section of accordion on loading another page with the same accordion, and make the accordion sections' states "bookmark-able" (latter is what you want, I think). Hope that helps. :)